# SectionList Header is imposing over ItemList in IOS

Tags: react-native

[image][![

```html
<View>
                        <SectionList
                            style={seasonsStyles.sectionListStyle}
                            renderItem={({ item, index, section }) => section.index === this.state.expandedRowId ? <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => this.getEpisodeScenes(section.season_id, item.episode_id)}
                                style={seasonsStyles.itemStyle}><Text style={seasonsStyles.episodeNameStyle}>{item.episode_name}</Text>
                                <View style={commonStyles.horizontalEndStyle}><Text style={seasonsStyles.seasonCountStyle}>{item.scene_count} Scenes</Text></View>
                            </TouchableOpacity> : null}
                            renderSectionHeader={({ section: { data, season_number, index } }) => (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    onPress={() => this.setState({ expandedRowId: this.state.expandedRowId === index ? null : index })}
                                    style={seasonsStyles.sectionHeaderStyle}>
                                    <View style={seasonsStyles.roundContainerStyle}>
                                        <Text style={seasonsStyles.seasonTitleStyle}>S{season_number}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={seasonsStyles.episodeInfoContainerStyle}>
                                        <Text style={seasonsStyles.seasonNumberStyle}>Season {season_number}</Text>
                                        <Text style={seasonsStyles.episeodeNumberStyle}>{data.length} Episodes</Text>
                                        <View style={seasonsStyles.directionIconStyle}>
                                            <Icon name={this.state.expandedRowId === index ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'} size={20} color={Colors.black} />
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            )}
                            sections={this.props.homeReducer.seasons}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
                            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
                                return <View style={seasonsStyles.separatorStyle} />
                            }}
                        />
                    </View>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtcpY.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtcpY.png)In SectionList my header is being overlapped by Section ItemList, it is happening in IOS only.
Can someone help me pls?
**This behaviour is happening while scrolling otherwise things are fine**

Comment: Please share the relevant code so we might help you.

Comment: Also, share the screenshots of the issue.

Comment: Please share the sectionHeaderStyle and other relevant styles in your question

Answer (score 7):

Could you try using **stickySectionHeadersEnabled** prop?

```
stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
```

[Description of stickySectionHeadersEnabled in VS Code since there is no explanation on react site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACZYx.png)

I develop on a windows machine and only have access to an Android emulator, so I cannot confirm firsthand that this works, unfortunately. Just wanted to give you what I think is a good lead. This is my first answer here, so I apologize if anything is unclear or wrong.